# How to set up an Asus N-14 N-300 USB WiFi adapter on macOS?

Tags: macos, wifi, usb, hardware, driver

I have an [Asus N-14 N-300 USB WiFi adapter](https://www.asus.com/Networking/USBN14/HelpDesk_Download/) and am trying to get it to work on macOS. It works well on my Linux machine.

I have installed drivers from the product's link.

If I go to `Apple > About this Mac > System Report > Hardware/USB` I see this info:

```
802.11 n WLAN:

  Product ID:   0x17e8
  Vendor ID:    0x0b05  (ASUSTek Computer Inc.)
  Version:  1.01
  Serial Number:    1.0
  Speed:    Up to 480 Mb/sec
  Manufacturer: Ralink
  Location ID:  0x14100000 / 7
  Current Available (mA):   500
  Current Required (mA):    450
  Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
```

How I can make macOS use the WiFi network?

Comment: Do you see a **Wi-Fi** option in **System Preferences > Network**?

Comment: A detected USB Wi-Fi adapter doesn't mean there's a driver for it.  Looking at the linked support page, the latest version of macOS supported is Mavericks (10.9).  It's possible this is no longer supported on later versions.

Comment: yep old driver from 2014..